# How to split list inside a dictionnary to create a new one?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, slice

I've been struggling on something for the day,

I have a dictionnary under the format

```
dict = {a:[element1, element2, element3], b:[element4, element5, element6]...}
```

I want a new dictionnary under the form

```
newdict = {a:element1, b:element4...}
```

Meaning only keeping the first element of the lists contained for each value.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#semantics):

```
{k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}
# {'a': 'element1', 'b': 'element4'}
```

Comment: Did not know the method ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

I like to check if the dictionary has a key before overwriting a keys value.

```
dict = {a:[element1, element2, element3], b:[element4, element5, element6]}

Python 2

newDict = {}
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    if k not in newDict:
        # add the first list value to the newDict's key
        newDick[k] = v[0]


Python 3

newDict = {}
for k, v in dict.items():
    if k not in newDict:
        # add the first list value to the newDict's key
        newDick[k] = v[0]
```

Comment: The test `k not in newDict` makes no sense. There are no duplicate keys in the source dict by definition.

Comment: Using `dict` as a variable name is a mistake.

Comment: @VPfB we dont know how each user / person will use this in the future. So we are planning ahead. And yes, dict isnt an ideal variable name, but I was using the data provided in the question.